# Bash script to get ASCII values for alphabet

Tags: bash, bash-script, ascii

How do I get the ASCII value of the alphabet?

For example, `97` for `a`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Define these two functions (usually available in other languages):

```
chr() {
  [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
  printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$1")"
}

ord() {
  LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$1"
}
```

Usage:

```
chr 65
A

ord A
65
```

Comment: @dmsk80: +1. For others like me who think they spot a typo: `"'A"` is correct whereas if you use `"A"` it will say : `A: invalid number` . It seems it's done on printf side (ie, in the shell, `"'A"` is indeed 2 chars, a `'` and a `A`. Those are passed to printf. And in the printf context, it is converted to the ascii value of A, (and is finally printed as a decimal thanks to the `'%d'`. Use `'Ox%x'` to show it in hexa or `'0%o'` to have it in octal))

Comment: -1 for not explaining how it works... joking :D, but seriously what do these `printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$1")"`, `'%03o'`, `LC_CTYPE=C` and the single quote in `"'$1"` do?

Comment: Read all [the detail in FAQ 71](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071). An excellent detailed analysis.

Answer (score 24):

You can see the entire set with:

```
$ man ascii
```

You'll get tables in octal, hex, and decimal.

Comment: There's also an ascii package for debian-based distros, but (at least now) the question is tagged as bash, so these wouldn't help the OP. In fact, it's installed on my system and all I get from man ascii is its man page.

Answer (score 22):

This works well,

```
echo "A" | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t uC

echo "A"                              ### Emit a character.
         | tr -d "\n"                 ### Remove the "newline" character.
                      | od -An -t uC  ### Use od (octal dump) to print:
                                      ### -An  means Address none
                                      ### -t  select a type
                                      ###  u  type is unsigned decimal.
                                      ###  C  of size (one) char.
```

exactly equivalent to:

```
echo -n "A" | od -An -tuC        ### Not all shells honor the '-n'.
```

Comment: Can you maybe add a small explanation?

Comment: tr to remove "\n" (new line ) from the input. od is used to -t dC is to print in decimal character.

Comment: `echo -n` suppresses trailing newline eliminating the need for `tr -d "\n"`

Comment: @Gowtham, only with some implementations of `echo`, not in Unix compliant echos for instance. `printf %s A` would be the portable one.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to extend it to UTF-8 characters (assuming you're in a UTF-8 locale):

```
$ perl -CA -le 'print ord shift' 
128520

$ perl -CS -le 'print chr shift' 128520
```

With `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` builtins:

```
$ printf "\U$(printf %08x 128520)\n"
```

Comment: Did you intend to put a square box character or else then the original char is not being displayed in the post and is being replaced by a square box character.

Comment: @mtk, You need a browser that displays UTF-8 and a font that has that [128520](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/128520) character.

Comment: I am on Latest Chrome, and don't think that it doesn't support UTF-8. Would like to know what browser you are on?

Comment: @mtk, `iceweasel` on `Debian sid`. The font as confirmed by iceweasel's web console is "DejaVu Sans" and I've got ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-core ttf-dejavu-extra packages installed which come from Debian with upstream at http://dejavu-fonts.org/

Comment: what is the base of 128520? my own [`ctbl()`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242794/52934) seems to properly enable me to display it, and to slice the char from the head of a string with `printf`, but it puts `4*((o1=360)>=(d1=240)|(o2=237)>=(d2=159)|(o3=230)>=(d3=152)|(o4=210)>=(d4=136))` in `$OPTARG` for the byte values.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going for the simple (and elegant?) Bash solution:

```
for i in {a..z}; do echo $(printf "%s %d" "$i" "'$i"); done
```

For in a script you can use the following:

```
CharValue="A"
AscValue=`printf "%d" "'$CharValue"
```

Notice the single quote before the CharValue. It is obligated...

Comment: How is your answer different from dsmsk80's answer?

Comment: My interpretation of the question is "how to get the ASCII values for the values of the alphabet". Not how to define a function to retrieve the ASCII value for one character.   So my first answer is a short one-line command to get the ASCII values for the alphabet.

Comment: I get your point, but I still think the bottom line of both answer is `printf "%d"`.

Comment: I agree this is a crucial part of the process to get to the result, yet i didn't wanted to make the assumption that xmpirate knew about the "for i in" and the use of a range. If he wanted a list, this could be a real time-saver ;-). Also, future readers might find my additions helpful.

Answer (score 8):

```
ctbl()  for O                   in      0 1 2 3
        do  for o               in      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                do for  _o      in      7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
                        do      case    $((_o=(_o+=O*100+o*10)?_o:200)) in
                                (*00|*77) set   "${1:+ \"}\\$_o${1:-\"}";;
                                (140|42)  set   '\\'"\\$_o$1"           ;;
                                (*)       set   "\\$_o$1"               ;esac
                        done;   printf   "$1";   shift
                done
        done
eval '
ctbl(){
        ${1:+":"}       return "$((OPTARG=0))"
        set     "" ""   "${1%"${1#?}"}"
        for     c in    ${a+"a=$a"} ${b+"b=$b"} ${c+"c=$c"}\
                        ${LC_ALL+"LC_ALL=$LC_ALL"}
        do      while   case  $c in     (*\'\''*) ;; (*) ! \
                                 set "" "${c%%=*}='\''${c#*=}$1'\'' $2" "$3"
                        esac;do  set    "'"'\''\${c##*\'}"'$@";  c=${c%\'\''*}
        done;   done;   LC_ALL=C a=$3 c=;set "" "$2 OPTARG='\''${#a}*("
        while   [ 0 -ne "${#a}" ]
        do      case $a in      ([[:print:][:cntrl:]]*)
                        case    $a in   (['"$(printf \\1-\\77)"']*)
                                        b=0;;   (*)     b=1
                        esac;;  (['"$(  printf  \\200-\\277)"']*)
                                        b=2;;   (*)     b=3
                esac;    set    '"$(ctbl)"'     "$@"
                eval "   set    \"\${$((b+1))%"'\''"${a%"${a#?}"}"*}" "$6"'\''
                a=${a#?};set    "$((b=b*100+${#1}+${#1}/8*2)))" \
                                "$2(o$((c+=1))=$b)>=(d$c=$((0$b)))|"
        done;   eval "   unset   LC_ALL  a b c;${2%?})'\''"
        return  "$((${OPTARG%%\**}-1))"
}'
```

The first `ctbl()` - at the top there - only ever runs the one time. It generates the following output *(which has been filtered through `sed -n l` for printability's sake)*:

```
ctbl | sed -n l
```

---

```
 "\200\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t$
\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\
\035\036\037 !\\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?" "@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS\
TUVWXYZ[\\]^_\\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\177" "\200\201\202\203\
\204\205\206\207\210\211\212\213\214\215\216\217\220\221\222\223\224\
\225\226\227\230\231\232\233\234\235\236\237\240\241\242\243\244\245\
\246\247\250\251\252\253\254\255\256\257\260\261\262\263\264\265\266\
\267\270\271\272\273\274\275\276\277" "\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\
\307\310\311\312\313\314\315\316\317\320\321\322\323\324\325\326\327\
\330\331\332\333\334\335\336\337\340\341\342\343\344\345\346\347\350\
\351\352\353\354\355\356\357\360\361\362\363\364\365\366\367\370\371\
\372\373\374\375\376\377"$
```

...which are all 8-bit bytes *(less `NUL`)*, divided into four shell-quoted strings split evenly at 64-byte boundaries. The strings might be represented with octal ranges like *`\200\1-\77`*,*`\100-\177`*,*`\200-\277`*,*`\300-\377`*, where byte 128 is used as a place-holder for *`NUL`*.

The first `ctbl()`'s entire purpose for existence is to generate those strings so that `eval` may define the second `ctbl()` function with them literally embedded thereafter. In that way they can be referenced in the function without needing to generate them again each time they are needed. When `eval` does define the second `ctbl()` function the first will cease to be.

The top half of the second `ctbl()` function is mostly ancillary here - it is designed to portably and safely serialize any current shell state it might affect when it is called. The top loop will quote any quotes in the values of any variables it might want to use, and then stack all of the results in its positional parameters.

The first two lines, though, first immediately return 0 and set `$OPTARG` to same if the function's first argument does not contain at least one character. And if it does, the second line immediately truncates its first argument to only its first character - because the function only handles a character at a time. Importantly, it does this in the current locale context, which means that if a character might comprise more than a single byte, then, provided the shell properly supports multi-byte chars, it will not discard any bytes except those which are not in the first character of its first argument.

```
        ${1:+":"}       return "$((OPTARG=0))"
        set     "" ""   "${1%"${1#?}"}"
```

It then does the save loop if at all necessary, and afterward it redefines the current locale context to the C locale for every category by assigning to the *`LC_ALL`* variable. From this point on, a character can only consist of a single byte, and so if there were multiple bytes in the first character of its first argument, these should now be each addressable as individual characters in their own right.

```
        LC_ALL=C
```

It is for this reason that the second half of the function is a `while` *loop*, as opposed to a singly run sequence. In most cases it will probably execute only once per call, but, if the shell in which `ctbl()` is defined properly handles multi-byte characters, it *might* loop.

```
        while   [ 0 -ne "${#a}" ]
        do      case $a in      ([[:print:][:cntrl:]]*)
                        case    $a in   (['"$(printf \\1-\\77)"']*)
                                        b=0;;   (*)     b=1
                        esac;;  (['"$(  printf  \\200-\\277)"']*)
                                        b=2;;   (*)     b=3
                esac;    set    '"$(ctbl)"'     "$@"
```

Note that the above `$(ctbl)` command substitution is only ever evaluated once - by `eval` when the function is initially defined - and that forever after that token is replaced with the literal output of that command substitution as saved into the the shell's memory. The same is true of the two `case` pattern command substitutions. This function does not ever call a subshell or any other command. It will also never attempt to read or write input/output *(except in the case of some shell diagnostic message - which probably indicates a bug)*.

Also note that the test for loop continuity is not simply `[ -n "$a" ]`, because, as I found to my frustration, for some reason a `bash` shell does:

```
char=$(printf \\1)
[ -n "$char" ] || echo but it\'s not null\!
```

---

```
but it's not null!
```

...and so I explicitly compare `$a`'s len to 0 for each iteration, which, also inexplicably, behaves differently *(read: correctly)*.

The `case` checks the first byte for inclusion in any of our four strings and stores a reference to the byte's set in `$b`. Afterward the shell's first four positional parameters are `set` to the strings embedded by `eval` and written by `ctbl()`'s predecessor.

Next, whatever remains of the first argument is again temporarily truncated to its first character - which should now be assured to be a single byte. This first byte is used as a reference to strip from the tail of the string which it matched and the reference in `$b` is `eval`'d to represent a positional parameter so everything from the reference byte to the last byte in string can be substituted away. The other three strings are dropped from the positional parameters entirely.

```
               eval "   set    \"\${$((b+1))%"'\''"${a%"${a#?}"}"*}" "$6"'\''
               a=${a#?};set    "$((b=b*100+${#1}+${#1}/8*2)))" \
                                "$2(o$((c+=1))=$b)>=(d$c=$((0$b)))|"
```

At this point the byte's value *(modulo 64)* can be referenced as the string's len:

```
str=$(printf '\200\1\2\3\4\5\6\7')
ref=$(printf \\4)
str=${str%"$ref"*}
echo "${#str}"
```

---

```
4
```

A little math is then done to reconcile the modulus based on the value in `$b`, the first byte in `$a` is permanently stripped away, and output for the current cycle is appended to a stack pending completion before the loop recycles to check if `$a` is actually empty.

```
    eval "   unset   LC_ALL  a b c;${2%?})'\''"
    return  "$((${OPTARG%%\**}-1))"
```

When `$a` definitely is empty, all names and state - with the exception of *`$OPTARG`* - that the function affected throughout the course of its execution are restored to their previous state - whether set and not null, set and null, or unset - and the output is saved to `$OPTARG` as the function returns. The actual return value is one less than the total number of bytes in the first character of its first argument - so any single byte character returns zero and any multi-byte char will return more than zero - and its output format is a little strange.

The value `ctbl()` saves to `$OPTARG` is a valid shell arithmetic expression that, if evaluated, will concurrently set variable names of the forms *`$o1`*, *`$d1`*, *`$o2`*, *`$d2`* to decimal and octal values of all respective bytes in the first character of its first argument, but ultimately evaluate to the total number of bytes in its first argument. I had a specific kind of workflow in mind when writing this, and I think maybe a demonstration is in order.

I often find a reason to take a string apart with `getopts` like:

```
str=some\ string OPTIND=1
while   getopts : na  -"$str"
do      printf %s\\n "$OPTARG"
done
```

---

```
s
o
m
e

s
t
r
i
n
g
```

I probably do a little more than just print it a char per line, but anything's possible. In any case, I haven't yet found a `getopts` that will properly do *(strike that -  `dash`'s `getopts` does it char by char, but `bash` definitely doesn't)*:

```
str=ŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞş  OPTIND=1
while   getopts : na  -"$str"
do      printf %s\\n "$OPTARG"
done|   od -tc
```

---

```
0000000 305  \n 220  \n 305  \n 221  \n 305  \n 222  \n 305  \n 223  \n
0000020 305  \n 224  \n 305  \n 225  \n 305  \n 226  \n 305  \n 227  \n
0000040 305  \n 230  \n 305  \n 231  \n 305  \n 232  \n 305  \n 233  \n
0000060 305  \n 234  \n 305  \n 235  \n 305  \n 236  \n 305  \n 237  \n
0000100
```

Ok. So I tried...

```
str=ŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞş
while   [ 0 -ne "${#str}" ]
do      printf %c\\n "$str"    #identical results for %.1s
        str=${str#?}
done|   od -tc
```

---

```
#dash
0000000 305  \n 220  \n 305  \n 221  \n 305  \n 222  \n 305  \n 223  \n
0000020 305  \n 224  \n 305  \n 225  \n 305  \n 226  \n 305  \n 227  \n
0000040 305  \n 230  \n 305  \n 231  \n 305  \n 232  \n 305  \n 233  \n
0000060 305  \n 234  \n 305  \n 235  \n 305  \n 236  \n 305  \n 237  \n
0000100

#bash
0000000 305  \n 305  \n 305  \n 305  \n 305  \n 305  \n 305  \n 305  \n
*
0000040
```

That kind of workflow - the byte for byte/char for char kind - is one I often get into when doing tty stuff. At the leading edge of input you need to know char values as soon as you read them, and you need their sizes *(especially when counting columns)*, and you need characters to be *whole* characters.

And so now I have `ctbl()`:

```
str=ŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞş
while [ 0 -ne "${#str}" ]
do    ctbl "$str"
      printf "%.$(($OPTARG))s\t::\t$OPTARG\t::\t$?\t::\t\\$o1\\$o2\n" "$str"
      str=${str#?}
done
```

---

```
Ő   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=220)>=(d2=144))   ::  1   ::  Ő
ő   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=221)>=(d2=145))   ::  1   ::  ő
Œ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=222)>=(d2=146))   ::  1   ::  Œ
œ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=223)>=(d2=147))   ::  1   ::  œ
Ŕ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=224)>=(d2=148))   ::  1   ::  Ŕ
ŕ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=225)>=(d2=149))   ::  1   ::  ŕ
Ŗ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=226)>=(d2=150))   ::  1   ::  Ŗ
ŗ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=227)>=(d2=151))   ::  1   ::  ŗ
Ř   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=230)>=(d2=152))   ::  1   ::  Ř
ř   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=231)>=(d2=153))   ::  1   ::  ř
Ś   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=232)>=(d2=154))   ::  1   ::  Ś
ś   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=233)>=(d2=155))   ::  1   ::  ś
Ŝ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=234)>=(d2=156))   ::  1   ::  Ŝ
ŝ   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=235)>=(d2=157))   ::  1   ::  ŝ
Ş   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=236)>=(d2=158))   ::  1   ::  Ş
ş   ::  2*((o1=305)>=(d1=197)|(o2=237)>=(d2=159))   ::  1   ::  ş
```

Note that `ctbl()` doesn't actually define the `$[od][12...]` variables - it never has any lasting effect on any state but `$OPTARG` - but only puts the string in `$OPTARG` that *can be used* to define them - which is how I get the second copy of each char above by doing `printf "\\$o1\\$o2"` because they are set each time I evaluate `$(($OPTARG))`. But where I do it I'm also declaring a field length modifier to `printf`'s `%s` string argument format, and because the expression always evaluates to the total number of bytes in a character, I get the whole character on output when I do:

```
printf %.2s "$str"
```

Comment: You should compete in an obfuscated bash code contest!

Comment: @HelloGoodbye this isnt *bash code*. nor is this obfuscated. to see obfuscation, please refer to `[ "$(printf \\1)" ]|| ! echo but its not null!` meanwhile, feel free to better acquaint yourself with meaningful comment practice, unless you recommend an actual such contest...?

Comment: No, I don't, what I wrote was just another way of saying that your code is very confusing (at least to me), but maybe it wasn't supposed to be easily understandable. If it isn't bash, then what language is it?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye - this is POSIX `sh` command language. `bash` is a *bourne again* supraset of  same, and in large part a precipitous motivator for much of the care afforded above toward widely portable, self expanding and namespace honorable character sizes of any kind. `bash` should handle much of this already, but the `c` language `printf` was, and maybe is, deficient the capability above provided.

Comment: I'm still inclined to use printf "%d" "'$char" for the sake of simplicity and readability.  I'm curious what sort of problems this exposes me to that @mikeserv's solution addresses?  Is there more than just some control characters affecting the return code (which I believe was his point in the above comment)?

Comment: @AlexJohnson this is a universal fix for a somewhat infamous basic `printf` problem with multibyte characters.

Comment: Funnily enough, I just ran into a similar problem one line above the printf statement in question.  Iterating through a string with 'û' in it was looping an extra time on some machines, presumably because of a second byte caused by a locale setting.  Do you have a favorite article on handling these sorts of issues in bash?

Comment: @alexjohnsON given preference, no bash.

Answer (score 3):

Not a shell script, but works

```
awk 'BEGIN{for( i=97; i<=122;i++) printf "%c %d\n",i,i }'
```

Sample output

```
xieerqi:$ awk 'BEGIN{for( i=97; i<=122;i++) printf "%c %d\n",i,i }' | head -n 5                                    
a 97
b 98
c 99
d 100
e 101
```

Answer (score 3):

- select the symbol, then press CTRL+C
- open `konsole`
- and type: `xxd<press enter>`
- then press `<SHIFT+INSERT><CTRL+D>`

you get something like:

```
mariank@dd903c5n1 ~ $ xxd
û0000000: fb
```

you know the symbol you pasted has hex code `0xfb`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out the decimal representation of the UTF-8 value, I endorse dsmsk80's soluiton. If, on the other hand, you need to assign the value to a variable, there is a mechanism within Bash's `printf` that works faster. Let us assume that you want to assign the ascii value of "A" (which is 65 in decimal, and which we have assigned to a variable, `theChar`) to a variable `myVar`. Inlining dmsmsk80's `ord()` function we would get:

```
LC_CTYPE=C myVar=$(printf "%d" "'$theChar")
```

In order for this assignment to take place, the value harvested from `'$theChar` must be formatted in decimal characters and then parsed from decimal to the number 65 that is then stored in `myVar`. To avoid this formatting and parsing we can take advantage of the `-v` flag for `printf`, which assigns the value to be printed directly. The syntax is as follows:

```
LC_CTYPE=C printf -v myVar "%d" "'$theChar"
```

I discovered this because I needed to create a Bash script that gave me the Fowler-Noll-Vo hash for each line of a text file, which I quote here:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LC_CTYPE=C
prime=16777619                                             #FNV prime
ofset=2166136261                                           #FNV offset
mask=0xffffffff                                            #bitmask
cat $1 | while read line || [[ -n $line ]]                 #foreach line in file (w/o end return)
do
    hash=$ofset                                            #set hash to offset for line.
    for (( i=0; i<${#line}; i++ ))                         #foreach char in line
    do
        printf -v charVal "%d" "'${line:$i:1}"             #use printf -v trick.
        hash=$(( ( ( hash ^ charVal ) * prime ) & mask ))  #update FNV1-a hash for char.
    done
    printf "%08X\n" $hash                                  #print hash result for line.
done
```

Using the `-v` option, for assignment with `printf`, resulted in a 50X performance improvement, when run in Cygwin64.