# How to convert an emoticon specified by a U+xxxxx code to utf-8?

Tags: shell, character-encoding, unicode

Emoticons seem to be specified using a format of U+xxxxx
wherein each x is a hexadecimal digit.

For example, **U+1F615** is the [official Unicode Consortium code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)) for the "confused face"

As I am often confused, I have a strong affinity for this symbol.

The **U+1F615** representation is confusing to me because I thought the only encodings possible for unicode characters required 8, 16, 24 or 32 bits, whereas 5 hex digits require 5x4=20 bits.

I've discovered that this symbol seems to be represented by a completely different hex string in bash:

```
$echo -n  | hexdump
0000000 f0 9f 98 95                                    
0000004

$echo -e "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95"


$PS1=$'\xf0\x9f\x98\x95  >'
  >
```

I would have expected **U+1F615** to convert to something like **\x00 \x01 \xF6 \x15**.

I don't see the relationship between these 2 encodings?

When I lookup a symbol in the [official Unicode Consortium list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)), I would like to be able to use that code directly without having to manually convert it in this tedious fashion. i.e.

- finding the symbol on some web page
- copying it to the clipboard of the web browser
- pasting it in bash to echo through a hexdump   to discover the REAL code.

Can I use this 20-bit code to determine what the 32-bit code is?

Does a relationship exist between these 2 numbers?

Answer (score 24):

`UTF-8` is a variable length *encoding* of Unicode. It is designed to be superset of ASCII. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for details of the encoding. `\x00 \x01 \xF6 \x15` would be `UCS-4BE` or `UTF-32BE` encoding.

To get from the Unicode code point to the UTF-8 encoding, assuming the locale's charmap is UTF-8 (see the output of `locale charmap`), it's just:

```
$ printf '\U1F615\n'

$ echo -e '\U1F615'

$ confused_face=$'\U1F615'
```

The latter [will be in the next version of the POSIX standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249#c590).

AFAIK, that syntax was introduced in 2000 by the stand-alone GNU `printf` utility (as opposed to the `printf` utility of the GNU shell), brought to `echo`/`printf`/`$'...'` builtins first [by `zsh` in 2003](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2003/msg00223.html), ksh93 in 2004, bash in 2010 (though [not working properly there until 2014](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg10559.html)), but was obviously inspired by other languages.

`ksh93` also supports it as `printf '\x1f615\n'` and `printf '\u{1f615}\n'`.

`$'\uXXXX'` and `$'\UXXXXXXXX'` are supported by `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh93`, `mksh` and FreeBSD `sh`, GNU `printf`, GNU `echo`.

Some require all the digits (as in `\U0001F615` as opposed to `\U1F615`) though that's likely to change in future versions as POSIX will allow fewer digits. In any case, you need all the digits if the `\UXXXXXXXX` is to be followed by hexadecimal digits as in `\U0001F615FOX`, as `\U1F615FOX` would have been `$'\U001F615F'OX`.

Some expand to the characters in the current locale's encoding at the time the string is parsed or at the time it is expanded, some only in UTF-8 regardless of the locale. If the character is not available in the current locale's encoding, the behaviour varies between shells.

So, for best portability, best is to only use it in UTF-8 locales and use all the digits, and use it in `$'...'`:

```
printf '%s\n' $'\U0001F615'
```

Note that:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8; printf '%s\n' $'\U0001F615'
```

or:

```
{
  LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
  printf '%s\n' $'\U0001F615'
}
```

Will not work with all shells (including `bash`) because the `$'\U0001F615'` is *parsed* before `LC_ALL` is assigned. (also note that there's no guarantee that a system will have a locale called `C.UTF-8`)

You'd need:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8; eval "confused_face=$'\U0001F615'"
```

Or:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
printf '%s\n' $'\U0001F615'
```

(not within a compound command or function).

---

For the reverse, to get from the UTF-8 encoding to the Unicode code-point, see [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198849) or [that one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92468).

```
$ unicode  
U+1F615 CONFUSED FACE
UTF-8: f0 9f 98 95  UTF-16BE: d83dde15  Decimal: &#128533;

Category: So (Symbol, Other)
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)

$ perl -CA -le 'printf "%x\n", ord shift' 
1f615
```

Comment: Notice that if `\U1F615` is followed by another valid hexadecimal digit then that will be assumed to be part of the escape sequence. To make it work regardless of what it is followed by it has to have enough leading zeros to be exactly eight digits long: `\U0001F615`

Comment: @kasperd, thanks. Yes, it's worth noting. I've included that in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to convert from UTF-32 (big endian) to UTF-8

```
$ confused=$(echo -ne "\x0\x01\xF6\x15" | iconv -f UTF-32BE -t UTF-8)     
$ echo $confused
```

You'll notice your hex value `0x01F615` in there, padded with an extra leading 0 to fill 32 bits.

The Wikipedia page on [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) explains the transformation from a Unicode codepoint to its UTF-8 representation very clearly. But trying to do it yourself in shell scripting might not be the best idea.

[UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) is fixed-width, and the correspondence between codepoint and UTF-32 representation is trivial - the value is the same.

Answer (score 6):

Nice way to do it in your head or on paper:

1. Figure out how many bytes it will be: values under U+0080 are one byte, else under U+0800 are 2 bytes, else under U+10000 are 3 bytes, else 4 bytes. In your case, 4 bytes.
2. Convert hex to octal: `0373025`.
3. Starting at the end, peel off 2 octal digits at a time to get a sequence of octal values: `037` `030` `025`.
4. If you have fewer octal values than the expected number of bytes, add an extra 0 at the beginning: `000` `037` `030` `025`.
5. For all but the first, add on `0200` to get: `000` `0237` `0230` `0225`.
6. For the first, add `0300` if the expected length is 2, `0340` if it's 3, or `0360` if it's 4, to get: `360` `0237` `0230` `0225`.

Now write as a string of octal escapes: `\360\237\230\225`. Optionally convert back to hex if you want.